# How to get data from dial intent in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, deep-linking, intentfilter

I am new to react native and trying to make an app that works with user contacts. I wanted android to suggest my app when the user clicks on any phone number or links in other apps, and I achieved that with the code below in AndroidManifest.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*ashnamoon.ir" android:path="tel/*" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*ashnamoon.ir" android:path="tel/*" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
    <data android:scheme="ashnamoon" android:host="*ashnamoon.ir" android:path="tel/*" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**My problem** is that I can't access URI data in my react native app when the user clicks on phone numbers which I think uses the dial action because I get the data when the user clicks on links like

```
<a href="http://www.ashnamoon.ir/tel/09113966092">test this link http</a>
<a href="tel:09113966091">test this phone</a>
```

**my code for getting data**

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import {Linking} from 'react-native';
import {useQueryContext} from '../provider/QueryProvider';
import {stripTelUrl} from './stripTelUrl';
import {useMount} from './useMount';

export const useInitialURL = () => {
  const {setQuery} = useQueryContext();
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(true);

  useMount(() => {
    const subscription = Linking.addEventListener('url', ({url}) => {
      if (url) {
        try {
          const stripedUrl = stripTelUrl(url);
          setQuery(stripedUrl);
        } catch (e) {}
      }
    });

    const getUrlAsync = async () => {
      const initialUrl: any = await Linking.getInitialURL();

      if (initialUrl) {
        try {
          const stripedUrl = stripTelUrl(initialUrl);
          setQuery(stripedUrl);
        } catch (e) {}
      }
      setProcessing(false);
    };

    getUrlAsync();

    return () => {
      subscription && subscription.remove();
    };
  });

  return {processing};
};
```